# I Want to Hide a Link in my Navbar While Logged In (Using CodeIgniter as my framework)

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, session

I'm attempting to hide the "Register" link in my navbar after the page checks if someone is logged in. I'm using CodeIgniter as my framework.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>

            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>reports">Reports <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>

            <li ><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>users/register">Register <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        </ul>
```

I used this to check if someone is logged in before it shows the logout button and it works fine and dandy.

```
<?php if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')): ?>

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

      <li><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>users/logout">Logout</a></li>

      </ul>

      <?php endif;?>
```

However, I've seen to run into a snag when trying to do it to hide the Register link. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its should be like this

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>reports">Reports <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <?php if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')){ ?>
           <li ><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>users/register">Register <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
```